# Signing off a forwarding contract

Tags: contract-development

I've recently started developing contracts on Ethereum.

I currently have a contract which is a forwarding contract. The idea is that it sits there until 2 parties "sign" it, once that is done, the contract proceeds to create a child contract.

What we are struggling with is the signing of the contract by both parties, I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of some documentation or explain how it is done...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look on the "standardish" multisig wallet contact https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/MultisigWallet.sol and how it does `confirm()`

Comment: In fact this operation could be with a standard multisig wallet, as I am pretty sure `execute` can handle any transaction, including contract creation,